# Should I try send extra documents, after accidentally submitting an application without them?

Tags: applications, cover-letter

I just sent off an application for an internship. I included a CV that was partially tailored for the company (I didn't rewrite my generic one, but changed it to emphasize skills relevant to the position). In the application there was an option to add extra documents such as cover letters.

I had done the application before (last year) and thought I remembered lots of questions in the application which would of covered everything I would of liked to of said in the cover letter. I remembered wrong and there was no such questions, and my application sent. I can't add extra documents to the application now (using the online form)

My question is would it be worthwhile to send a cover letter to human resources to be included with my application, or will this give the impression that I'm incompetent (that I couldn't even fill out an application form...)?

My cover letter from last year seems to still be on their system, I'm not sure if this will be looked at. I would basically just modify this one if I was to send another, because most the content is still relevant

Related : [Is a cover letter really necessary?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17745/is-a-cover-letter-really-necessary) (but with some differing advice)

Thanks in advance

Edit: I am in the UK and the job (and my background) is IT/Engineering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is would it be worthwhile to send a cover letter to human
>   resources to be included with my application, or will this give the
>   impression that I'm incompetent (that I couldn't even fill out an
>   application form...)?

Yes, you should attempt to send your additional information now.

Mistakes happen. Submission forms vary at each company. It's hard to remember the details for each.

Just send you information, indicate that you forgot to attach it to your original submission, and hope for the best.

(If this causes the company to think you are incompetent, then omitting the information would likely do the same. I suspect you are over-thinking this a bit.)

Comment: Yes I suspect I am over-thinking it a bit, but I don't have a lot of experience with these things so I thought I'd ask the excellent community here :) Thanks Joe !