# No cover letter upload available

Tags: cover-letter

I have found a few on-line application sites that only allow resume uploads. Should I add a cover letter as first page of my resume, or is it considered bad form / improper to do so.  Why or why not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I include a cover letter?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/60611/should-i-include-a-cover-letter)

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt Different animal entirely.  This is what to do if there is no visible means to upload a cover letter.

Comment: @RichardU Oh, all right!

Comment: Why not put the cover letter as the last page along the lines 'Thank you for reading my CV. I would like to highlight the following that might be of a benefit to the role and the company'

Answer (score 14):

> I have found a few on-line application sites that only allow resume
>   uploads. Should I add a cover letter as first page of my resume?

**No.**

If the website doesn't provide a way to upload cover letters, then that means they don't want one.

And if the first page of your document is a cover letter, then it's possible that the reader may just discard your application without even realizing that your resume is at the back.

Just supply whatever it is that they are asking for and omit anything else.

Comment: Important point.  If their process is looking for resume data only, and you throw in a cover letter, it could corrupt the output file and you've ruined your chances.

Answer (score 1):

You should not.

The employer has established the rules and expectations by how they designed the application.  Trying to go around the rules because you don't like them is not likely to endear you to any employer.  That might be acceptable when you have an extended tenure within the company, but when you are trying to get in, follow the rules and do things their way.

Personally, I don't place much value on the cover letters I receive.  There is very little of verifiable value you can explain in a cover letter that isn't in your resume.

Maybe my perspective is off because it seems every cover letter I receive is from a "*motivated self-starter with excelent writen and oral comunication skill*"

Comment: Just curious, do you think cover letters are becoming obsolete?

Comment: @RichardU, I wouldn't say that necessarily.  I still see plenty of places where you can upload a cover letter or the application includes a "tell us about yourself" section.  I just don't see much value in a cover letter.  When I am hiring, I am looking for someone who can get the job done.  What are you going to put in your cover letter, that isn't already in your resume or portfolio, that will convince me to give you an interview.

Comment: Not a dang thing, that's why I asked.